# Redirecitng a URL into a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a web page named Home.html. inside it there's div tag with the id "Loading_Page". I loaded  AccessForms.php into it using jQuery load() method. #AccessForm is a link given in Home page.

```
$( "#AccessForm" ).click(function() {


   $("#Loading_Page").load('AccessForms.php');
   return false;
});
```

After submitting the data inside AccessForm.php I need to load the same page where I was earlier. Not the bare home page. Home page + the AccessForm.php. But when I redirect the location it loads again only the Home page without AccessForm.php. How can I redirect to the same format where I was earlier before submitting?

```
echo "<script>alert ('The lecture was recorded successfully');
 window.location.href='Home.php';
 </script>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options to maintain that state.
1. You can pass some special parameters in query string and base on query string you can load that pages.
2. you can use javascript window.back functionality which will show's you window previous page where you can get the allthe details.

Give a try. or let me know more on details.

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying.. Instead of using window.location.href='Home.php', I used window.history.go(-1)
Is the approach I have used correct? But the problem is it shows the earlier entered values too.. How can I change it?

Comment: if your using history.go(-1) javascript function then there is no chance to remove or reset all the text box values . if you want to clear all the fileds /text box values you need to use redirect page option (1st option) becuase page need to reload to clear the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

There's two parts to this problem:

1. You will need to tell Home.php that it has to load something inside the div
2. You will need Home.php to listen.

Here's an easy JavaScript / jQuery solution (using `$_GET` parameters so theoretically you could also use PHP to do parts of this):

When redirecting, add a parameter that includes which page to load into Loading_Page:

```
window.location.href='Home.php?Loading_Page=AccessForms.php';
```

On loading the Home.php page, read this parameter and do something with it (put it inside the jQuery ready function).

```
var vars = getUrlVars()
if(vars["Loading_Page"]) {
    $('#Loading_Page').load(vars["Loading_Page"]);
}


// snippet taken from http://jquery-howto.blogspot.nl/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html    
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Comment: Hi... Thanx for replying... Could you please let me explain me what this says.....................
  var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

Comment: `slice` cuts off the part before the ?, and because the `+1` was added it also cuts off the ? itself. What's left is a string of parameters (`param=test&this=that&bla=bla`). `.split()` then splits up that string at the '&', and creates an array of all the pieces. The array in this example will contain `["param=test", "this=that", "bla=bla"]`. The following function then loops through that and selects the one that you need.